# Meta-programming problem with Enums

Tags: c++, dynamic, enums

Atm i have sth like that:

```
template<int n>
struct Pow
{
  enum{val= Pow<n-1>::val<<1};
};
template<>
struct Pow<0>{
    enum{val =1};
};
```

I can acess data like Pow<30>::val. It's good but i want do like this

```
   int main()
    {
    Pow<30>::val;
```

and then use variable to
access all of value <0,30>
     I knew that i can use array and dynamic programming but can i do that in this way?
Sorry for English.

Comment: How do you want to "access" the values?  Add them all up?  Call some function on each of the values?

Comment: I don't understand. How is `Pow<n>::val` supposed to be different for every conceivable purpose from `1 << n` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using C++0x variadic templates:

```
template<int... Indices>
struct powers {
    static const int value[sizeof...(Indices)];

    typedef powers<Indices..., sizeof...(Indices)> next;
};

template<int... Indices>
const int powers<Indices...>::value[sizeof...(Indices)] = { Pow<Indices>::val... };

template<int N>
struct build_powers {
    typedef typename build_powers<N - 1>::type::next type;
};

template<>
struct build_powers<1> {
    typedef powers<0> type;
};
```

and then:

```
int
main()
{
    // we want [0..30] inclusive so pass 31 as exclusive upper limit
    typedef build_powers<31>::type power_type;
    // 0..30 is 31 powers in all
    typedef const int array_type[31];

    array_type& ref = power_type::value;
    // ref[0] .. ref[30] are the values of Pow<0>::val .. Pow<30>::val
}
```

So that's with using an array but without dynamic initialization. Since you want the result as a variable and not for TMP I feel this is adequate.

Comment: Thx very i was searching for sth like that :)

Answer (score 1):

When you do `Pow<30>::val;` you will instantiate the top of your two templates, then when it get's to zero it will instantiate the specialization, and only the final result will be visible at *runtime*, since templates are resolved at **compile time**

Comment: Thx :(I was thinking that meta-programming is more powerfull.

Comment: @Waskae : The fact that it's all performed at compile-time rather than runtime is what _makes_ TMP powerful...